# Splitting text files in folder

Tags: linux, bash, split

I have been trying to make a shell script that will split text files one after the other through an entire folder and deposit every split chunk into another designated folder.

Here is what I have so far, I know its probably clunky(have never tried writing a .sh before):

```
#!/bin/bash
#File Split Automation

echo "Usage: split [Folder w/ Input] [Folder For Outputs] [Options] [PREFIX]
  Options: -b [sizeMB]: Split by size
  -l [No. of Lines]: Split by Lines
  If No Output Folder is Defined Default is Set To: /Desktop/splitter-parts
  If No Options Are Selected Default is Size=100MB"

inputdirc=$1
outputdirc=$2
spltion=$3
meastick=$4
prefixture=$5

if [ -d $1 ]
then
    echo "You Picked The Folder $1 To Split Files From"
    ls $1
else
    exit
fi

if [ -d $2 ]
then
    echo "Please Confirm Folder Path For Output $outputdirc"
else
    cd /root/Desktop/
    mkdir -p splitter-parts
fi



read -t 10 -p "Press Enter Or Wait 5 Sec. To Continue"


cd $2

for swordfile in $( ls $1); 
do
command -p split $3 $4 -a 3 -d $swordfile $5

done
```

Anything you see going wrong? Because I am not getting the output I desired, though it functioned fine when I just had a file and a folder in the split-command string.

EDIT::::

Sorry, I apologize. Just getting a bit ahead of myself.

This is what I am seeing when I run it:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/Wordlists# ./splitter.sh '/root/Desktop/Wordlists'               '   /root/Desktop/Untitled Folder' s 100MB
Usage: split [Folder w/ Input] [Folder For Outputs] [Options] [PREFIX]
Options: -b [sizeMB]: Split by size
-l [No. of Lines]: Split by Lines
If No Output Folder is Defined Default is Set To: /Desktop/splitter-parts
If No Options Are Selected Default is Size=100MB
You Picked The Folder /root/Desktop/Wordlists To Split Files From
10dig10milup2.txt                     mixed.txt
10dig10miluplow2.txt                      movie-characters.txt
10dig10miluplow3.txt                      name1s.txt
((------------------CUT------------)
lower.lst                         xae2.txt
lower.txt                         xaf2.txt
mangled.lst                       xag2.txt
mangled.txt                       xah6.txt
misc-dictionary.txt
./splitter.sh: line 24: [: /root/Desktop/Untitled: binary operator expected
Press Enter Or Wait 5 Sec. To Continue
./splitter.sh: line 37: cd: /root/Desktop/Untitled: No such file or directory
split: extra operand `10dig10milup2.txt'
Try `split --help' for more information.
split: extra operand `10dig10miluplow2.txt'
Try `split --help' for more information.
split: extra operand `10dig10miluplow3.txt'
Try `split --help' for more information.
split: extra operand `10dig10miluplow4.txt'
Try `split --help' for more information.
...................MORE OF THE SAME.......
```

As far as what I am supposed to see, I haven't gotten that far yet, clearly I am missing some steps.

Comment: "I am not getting the output I desired" isn't a clear problem statement. It would allow us to help you better if you made your input and desired output clear and explained exactly what problem you're having.

Comment: Do you think we can guess what script output is right and what output is wrong? Provide examples showing right and wrong outputs.

Comment: Why do you define shell variables which are not used?

Comment: Jdamian- are you referring to $1 $2 etc.?

Comment: I think Jdamian is referring to the first assignments, like `inputdirc=$1`, and then you go ahead and use `$1` in the code, rather than `$inputdirc`. Good luck.

Comment: Many of the error messages don't make sense. Is it possible that you're saving the script in one window while you're running it in another? If you get this same output several times, then use shell "exit on first error" setting (`set -e`) and shell debug/trace features of `set -x` or `set -vx` and look at the first error. You'll see a line with `+` at the front. What you'll see on that line is the actual command that was executed with variables replaced with string values. Then you can see what is causing `./splitter.sh: line 24: [: /root/Desktop/Untitled: binary operator expected`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for all the input.

Like I said first time ever trying something like this, I know my way around my chromatography columns but thats about all, not saying that helps me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick rewrite with some notes to follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
#File Split Automation

usage="Usage: split [Options] [Folder w/ Input] [Folder For Outputs] [PREFIX]
  Options: -b [sizeMB]: Split by size
  -l [No. of Lines]: Split by Lines
  If No Output Folder is Defined Default is Set To: /Desktop/splitter-parts
  If No Options Are Selected Default is Size=100MB"

split_opt="-b 100MB"
while getopts hb:l: opt; do
    case $opt in
        h) echo "$usage"; exit ;;
        b) split_opt="-b $OPTARG" ;;
        l) split_opt="-l $OPTARG" ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "$usage"
    exit 1
fi

inputdirc=$1
if [[ -d $inputdirc ]]; then
    ls $1
else
    echo "no such directory: $inputdirc" >&2
    exit 1
fi

if [[ -n $2 ]]; then
    outputdirc=$2
else
    outputdirc=/root/Desktop/splitter-parts
fi

prefixture=$3

mkdir -p "$outputdirc"
cd "$outputdirc"

for swordfile in "$inputdirc"/*; do
    command -p split $split_opt -a 3 -d "$swordfile" $prefixture 
done
```

Notes:

- you generally want to quote **all** your variables. This is the cause of your error, because there was a file with whitespace and square brackets in the name.
- I did not quote a couple in the `split` command because I specifically want the shell to perform [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) on the values
- since options are, well, optional, use `getopts` to collect them.
- you store the positional parameters in variables, but you continue to use the positional parameters. Pick one or the other.

Comment: You still have an unquoted `ls $1`. Also, for `split_opt`, you should definitely use an array (question is tagged Bash) and quote appropriately. How about the quoting of `prefixture` in the `split` command? it's subject to pathname expansions! you could use `set -f` (but meh…).

Comment: Also, every `cd` should be followed by an explicit check, whether the `cd` succeeded or not.

Comment: Wow!!! Thanks so much man, honestly I would have never gotten that far in the textbook tonight. I wish I took computer science in highschool.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, some good points. `prefixture` is unquoted because if it's unset, I don't want to pass an empty string to `split`, I want to not pass that arg at all. If the user wants the split files to be prefixed with `*` or `?`, they can shoot themselves in the foot some other way.

Comment: Thanks everyone..I ended up using "$swordfile" "$swordfile" in the command-split line and it did exactly what I wanted.